# Random.shuffle surprisingly doesn't work inside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, shuffle

Random.shuffle surprisingly doesn't work inside loop, it always produce the same shuffled list, but i need 19 **different** lists in order:

```
for i in range(19):
    random.seed() #random.randint(1, 50)
    random.shuffle(candidates_random_list)
    random.seed()
    candidates_full_list.append(candidates_random_list)
print('candidates_full_list ----- \n\n ')
pprint(candidates_full_list)
```

I saw a lot of tutorials and expected seed() will solve this, but it is in my opinion misbehavior. Every run it shuffle, but not in loop.

Comment: Could you show a minimal output of what you are expecting from the code and what you are actually observing?

Comment: May be intersting to you : https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/

Comment: `random.shuffle()` shuffles the list in place and you're not making copies. Therefore you're just appending the same list multiple times.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just get rid of those `random.seed()` lines and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shuffle` is in-place, and your list contains 19 references to the same list, not separate lists resulting from each shuffle.

Store a copy of the shuffled list instead.

```
for i in range(19):
    random.shuffle(candidates_random_list)
    candidates_full_list.append(candidates_random_list[:])
```

Comment: Isn't it clearer to say `candidates_full_list += candidates_random_list` ?

Comment: No, that's equivalent to `candidates_full_list.extend(candidates_random_list)`; it adds the *elements* of the argument to the list, rather than the argument itself.

Comment: Oh yes, OP is after a list of lists!